# Detect User Activity to Keep Session Alive Strategy (RxJS)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, polling

I want to keep the user session alive with user activity defined as such.

> The information system shall initiate locking of an interactive
> session after a 15 minute period of user inactivity (inactivity
> defined as no keyboard or mouse activity).

This is what i came up with.. as usual there are many ways to accomplish something in RxJS and i was wondering if there is a better way or a standard strategy

Below example will Ping the server if there is user activity every 60 seconds

```js
const userActivityEvents = [
      fromEvent(document, 'click'),
      fromEvent(document, 'wheel'),
      fromEvent(document, 'scroll'),
      fromEvent(document, 'keypress'),
      fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
      fromEvent(document, 'touchmove'),
    ];

    merge(...userActivityEvents).pipe(
      throttleTime(60 * 1000),
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.get('/api/auth/ping', new HttpParams(), new HttpHeaders({ignoreLoadingBar: ''})),
      ),
    ).subscribe({error: () => undefined});
```

Comment: what is `{leading: true, trailing: false}`?

Comment: those were the defaults https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime
i updated the question and removed them, as they werent adding anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there has been no traction on this i might as well leave my final answer.

```js
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        merge(
          fromEvent(document, 'click'),
          fromEvent(document, 'wheel'),
          fromEvent(document, 'scroll'),
          fromEvent(document, 'keypress'),
          fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
          fromEvent(document, 'touchmove'),
        ).pipe(
          throttleTime(USER_ACTIVITY_POLL_TIME),
          skip(1),
          filter(() => !this.sessionModal),
          filter(() => this.authService.authenticated),
          switchMap(() => this.authService.ping(new HttpHeaders({ignoreLoadingBar: ''}))),
        ).subscribe({error: () => undefined});
      });
```